# How can I go about debugging this SIGSEV in gdb?

Tags: gdb, qnx

I am building previously working code, but I am getting a seg fault and I can't figure out what went wrong. gdb catches the error, but it doesn't point to an obvious cause. The source line it shows is a function name, so it doesn't even get into the function. If I look at the dissasembly of the instruction it is still setting up the stack, so maybe the stack is messed up. So how should I go about debugging this? This is in QNX 6.2, console gdb only.

```
0x0816b829 in __ml (this=0x79b963c, anMultiplier=0) at ../u_matrix.cpp:56
56      tcMatrix tcMatrix::operator*(float64 anMultiplier)

0x816b820 <__ml>:       push   %ebp
0x816b821 <__ml+1>:     mov    %esp,%ebp
0x816b823 <__ml+3>:     sub    $0x13ac,%esp
0x816b829 <__ml+9>:     push   %edi
0x816b82a <__ml+10>:    push   %esi
0x816b82b <__ml+11>:    push   %ebx
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instruction you are crashing on is `push %edi`.

This most likely means that you have a stack overflow.

One likely cause of stack overflow is infinite recursion. If `(gdb) where` shows unending stream of function calls, that's your problem.

If `where` shows reasonable sequence of calls, execute `info frame` and `up` repeatedly, looking for frames with unreasonably large size.

Finally, the problem may be caused by a change in your execution environment, and not by anything in your program. I am not sure what QNX equivalent of `ulimit -s` is, but it's possible that your stack limit is simply too small.

Answer (score 3):

Following Employed Russian's answer:

ulimit -s works on QNX but it is unlimited by default.

I would experiment with

ldrel -S2M -L yourexecutablename

to adjust the initial stack allocation / laziness to see if coredumps reoccur. You can also use QCC's -N flag to set the initial stack size higher.

Answer (score 1):

Anything relevant if doing a "bt" in gdb?

Answer (score 1):

"this" pointer looks messed up - 0x79b963c seems to be off but it is possible depending on how objects are initialized. Try

print *this

and see if data makes sense or is garbage. It also looks like your source doesn't match the executable - the line you have in the example looks like an operator override declaration and not something executable.

I would ignore the particular line, look for the whole _ml function in the source and try printing a few local variables to see if maybe you are within a loop or some other scope that would have them.

I am guessing you have a matrix multiplication operator where a matrix is multiplied by a float - most likely this is something like index out of bounds, off-by-one problem of some sort where you ran outside of the memory scope and corrupted the stack.

like Unknown said, try bt as well - if it comes back with a lot of ??()'s then you do have a corrupt stack.

Answer (score 1):

`QNX` does now appear to support `valgrind` (at least from 6.5 onwards):

http://community.qnx.com/sf/frs/do/viewRelease/projects.valgrind/frs.valgrind.valgrind_3_10

Comment: Other responses don't necessarily follow the question (in gdb) either, +1 to counter downvote.

Answer (score -1):

You could also try valgrind'ing it, which can give more info.

Comment: Since when does Valgrind support QNX?

Comment: whoops, my mistake, sorry about that